# Ionic App not asking for push notifications permission

Tags: ionic-framework

I have the right provisioning and development profiles set (build succeeds and I am able to push to testflight too), but I still dont see it asking for permissions, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it will ask for permission when you try to register for push to try get the token.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, have configured my app with OneSignal, it's already working for production but for some reason for a new build in TestFlight is not working anymore, it does not ask for permissions.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any solution?